# Prevent modal from reloading after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to build a tool that has a modal which opens on page load, then the user would paste text into a textarea and submit. After that a function should run that returns a substring of that text for a specific number of characters.

Currently I am console logging the correct substring, but after I click the submit button, the modal runs again. I only want the modal to run once on page load.

Can anyone offer some guidance?

```js
$(window).on('load',function() {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
 
 
});

function myFunction(info) {
 var info = $('#textArea').val();
  var result = info.substring(0, 66);
 
 
 $('#result').html(result);
 console.log(result);
 
}
```

```css
.container >* {
 margin:20px auto;
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome to my Bringhurst Rule Tool</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Bringhurst introduces designers to the "66 character rule," which states that 66 characters including special characters and spaces at a font-size of 16px is the ideal width for a single line of type in order to achieve maximum clarity and readability.</p>
     <p>Close the modal to see what your 66 characters look like.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div> <!-- footer end -->
   </div> <!-- modal-content end -->
  </div> <!-- modal dialog end -->
 </div> <!-- mymodal end -->
 
 <div class="container">
  <header><h1>Bringhurst Rule</h1></header>
  <form class="align-center">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea"></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="Paste your text here..."></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()">Get the substring!</button>
  </form>
  
  
 </div>
 <div id="result"></div>
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to do what you're doing, like using jQuery's fancy event handlers instead of using inline event handlers, but the easiest answer to your question is to return false on the event.. do that by making two changes..

1. Make the event listener return the result of the event handler by changing the HTML like so.. `onclick="return myFunction()"` (added the `return` there)
2. `return false` from the function itself.

By returning false you're preventing the default action, which is to submit the form.

Alternatively you could remove the form itself or change the submit button to a regular button.

```js
$(window).on('load',function() {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
 
 
});

function myFunction(info) {
 var info = $('#textArea').val();
  var result = info.substring(0, 66);
 
 
 $('#result').html(result);
 console.log(result);
 return false;
}
```

```css
.container >* {
 margin:20px auto;
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome to my Bringhurst Rule Tool</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Bringhurst introduces designers to the "66 character rule," which states that 66 characters including special characters and spaces at a font-size of 16px is the ideal width for a single line of type in order to achieve maximum clarity and readability.</p>
     <p>Close the modal to see what your 66 characters look like.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div> <!-- footer end -->
   </div> <!-- modal-content end -->
  </div> <!-- modal dialog end -->
 </div> <!-- mymodal end -->
 
 <div class="container">
  <header><h1>Bringhurst Rule</h1></header>
  <form class="align-center">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea"></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="Paste your text here..."></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="return myFunction()">Get the substring!</button>
  </form>
  
  
 </div>
 <div id="result"></div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the tips and the help. You mentioned using jQuery more vs. inline event handlers. Any guidance on that? I would love to get better. Thanks again.

Comment: @JosephRomero  - Take a peek at [the official tutprial](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/), if you need help converting this specific code that should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent the page reloading after the submition and you can return as `false` `onclick` event;

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Get the substring!</button>
```

```js
$(window).on('load',function() {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
 
 
});
function myFunction() {
  var info = $('#textArea').val();
  var result = info.substring(0, 66);
  $('#result').html(result);
  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
.container >* {
 margin:20px auto;
 width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome to my Bringhurst Rule Tool</h4>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Bringhurst introduces designers to the "66 character rule," which states that 66 characters including special characters and spaces at a font-size of 16px is the ideal width for a single line of type in order to achieve maximum clarity and readability.</p>
     <p>Close the modal to see what your 66 characters look like.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div> <!-- footer end -->
   </div> <!-- modal-content end -->
  </div> <!-- modal dialog end -->
 </div> <!-- mymodal end -->
 
 <div class="container">
  <header><h1>Bringhurst Rule</h1></header>
  <form class="align-center">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textArea"></label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="Paste your text here..."></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Get the substring!</button>
  </form>
  
  
 </div>
 <div id="result"></div>
 
</body>
```